# Kaiser window equation for attenuation doesn't match the figure

Tags: filters

In the article linked below, no paywall, their Figure 4 shows a Fourier transform of a Kaiser window with Alpha=8. In it, the attenuation is shown to be As ~ 30db.

Below the figure, their Equation 20 is as follows:

Alpha = 0.1102(As − 8.7) , As > 50

Alpha = 0.5842(As − 21)0.4 + 0.07886(As − 21), 21 < As < 50

Plugging in As = 30 returns Alpha ~ 2, not the eight listed in the figure. What is the author doing there?

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/357306924_Optimal_Order_of_Time-Domain_Adaptive_Filter_for_Anti-Jamming_Navigation_Receiver

Update: sometimes alpha is used, and sometimes beta = pi alpha. Pretty sure the author mixed them up.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [DSP Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/). But yes, it seems likely the author actually means $\pi\alpha$, despite saying $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check them out.